# Fedora Qt runtime packages

Tags: qt, installation, fedora, rpm

We wish to package our Qt-based application for Ubuntu and Fedora. In the Ubuntu Debian package, I include dependencies on, for example,

```
libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7)
libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7)
libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.7)
...
```

I am unable to find the corresponding runtime packages for Fedora 13 & 14. I have searched in the [Fedora Package Database](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb) and tried [RPM Search](http://rpm.pbone.net/), but none of my searches are coming up with anything that looks like the official distribution. (I'm assuming, of course, that there is one ... please correct me if I'm mistaken.)

Obviously, I'm quite unfamiliar with Fedora; it's not my daily OS, so I'm probably missing something obvious. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package names on Fedora are qt and qt-x11

I don't think they've changed between the releases, but the package names were taken from a Fedora 14 box.

The relevant piece of your spec might look like:

```
Requires: qt >= 4.7
Requires: qt-x11 >= 4.7
```

qt-x11 probably depends on qt so you may be able to DRY that up a bit.

Comment: +1 - would also recommend running "yum search qt" to check for any other potentially relevant packages.

Comment: So the framework is not broken up at all by module except for those two? I'm guessing qt-x11 = QtGui, and qt = QtCore + QtXml + QtNetwork + ... (everything else). `yum search qt | grep xml`, for example, returned nothing, so there's no qt-xml package or anything like that. That's kind of a bummer.

Comment: The only other framework that's broken out by the Fedora packages is qt-webkit.

Comment: Oh, and the database plugins are broken out as well. I initially forgot about those.